# Is there a way to use @spec (Function specs) to specify the function return as list of UUIDs?

Tags: function, elixir, specifications

I have a function called 'get' that returns a list of UUIDs. This list can be empty or can have N UUIDs. Is there a way to use @spec to expose this type of return? Until now my @specs is telling that a generic list is returning.

```
@spec get :: list
  def get do
    ...
    list_of_UUIDs
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Ecto.UUID.t()`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.UUID.html#t:t/0) is defined as

```elixir
@type t :: <<_::288>>
```

I would not reinvent the wheel and would use

```elixir
@spec get :: [<<_::288>>]
```

It is not precisely correct (not every `36` bytes are a valid *UUID*,) but much better than just `list()`.

For clarity, one might explicitly go with

```elixir
@type uuid :: <<_::288>>

@spec get :: [uuid()]
```

Comment: `<<_::128>>` if the UUID is binary - 288 is the number of bits required for the string representation including hyphens encoded in UTF-8.